# Anyone from Tamilnadu who has read Kamba Ramayana and can refute this guy's arguments?

Tags: ramayana, rama, valmiki, vali

I have studied Valmiki Ramayana but not Kamba ramayana.  I can also see he is at fault in a few places. but I like to hear from others. I am requesting answer from those who accept Rama as God, not as ordinary human being.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9R_kkYuvis

Comment: I think you can write the relevant portion (gist) in English it’ll be easier to understand what the question is asking and what you want refuted.

Comment: What is it that you want to be refuted? Pls write it down as part of question. Link questions / answers are difficult to interpret.

Comment: this is not a forum to refute or to confirm youtube videos. Please clarify your question with YOUR question. Please read the forum rules. Not a forum to ask for opinions.

Comment: Please post the arguments he mentioned in the video, otherwise it may not be apt for the site.